# change workspace of a ProcessBuilder Java

Tags: java, scripting, workspace

Im actually doing a Java Program that execute a shell script with this ProccesBuilder:

```
        ProcessBuilder builder = newProcessBuilder("sh","script.sh",params);
        builder.redirectOutput(new File("outNormal.txt"));
        builder.redirectError(new File("outError.txt"));
        Process p = builder.start();
        p.waitFor();
```

The problem i have is that outNormal.txt and outError.txt, and another file my script creates are placed at the same level as /src and /bin, and i want to change this to a new directory.

is this possible?

Comment: Where are /src and /bin? Is that the CWD where you run your program?

Comment: yes, and i want to move this files into /src/resources/output/

Comment: You can name your files as such. ie `new File("resources/output/outNormal.txt");` Note that when you start a path with '/' it implies absolute location and not relative.

Comment: I dont know how i didnt realice that i could solve this so easily... Thanks!!